# ORACLE to SQL Server SSIS JOB Failing unicode issue Successful when not ran as job

Tags: sql-server, oracle, unicode, ssis

I am trying to import Oracle data to SQL Server and keep getting an error telling me that it  cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types but the SSIS package works when I run it initially.

I am dropping the table (which is completing successfully) at the beginning of the job, but when the proxy trys to start inserting the data into the new table it creates it fails...

I am using a proxy and `/DECRYPT` with the password and that part seems to be working fine it is just not wanting to accept the field formats...

Comment: Are you certain that you have the exact same drivers on the machine it works on - not run as a sql agent job versus the server it's running via job? What about all your tnsnames settings and configurations?

Comment: I ran it via remote desktop from the server to make sure that was not the issue... :(  I created the SSIS package and ran it initially from the server as well to make sure that would not be an issue.

Comment: Well then, +1 for covering the basics. Unfortunately, this is about as far as I've been with Oracle related to SSIS. Best I can think of is take your command line call that works when you RDP in; create a credential as your RDP'ed self; Create an sql agent job and use that proxy to run the same package (ensure you explicitly reference the 32 or 64 bit version of dtexec) and see whether that works. Possibly post the job definition here as well obscuring that which needs obscured.

Comment: So I figured it out when I was looking at the command line... when I added the password to the cmd line it broke the line between USER and ID because the rest of the cmd line was one continuous string and was not properly logging in to oracle.  I put a space / line break after the semicolon for the password and it works fine now.  Thank you!